# Click on form does not click underlying control

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a windows forms application. When I click on a window this activates the form and then I need to click again to call the particular control click event. For example if I click on a button this activates the form and then I need to click the button again.

Is there a way to perform the control click and window activation in one click? Preferably I would want this to work with whatever the clickable control is (menu,button, label etc)

So far I have managed to activate the win form on mouse over and then the control click works. I would like to have the win form activated on click and also run the click command on an underlying control if this has a click event.

Comment: What do you mean by activates - do you mean gets focus or that an event is fired or what?

Comment: @ScruffyDuck Apologies if this was not clear. If the form is not the active form the first click activates the form. What I need to do is to also click on the control on the form with the same click so the user clicks once to run the control.

Comment: So are you saying that clicking directly on the button does not activate and execute the button?

Comment: This sounds strange to me. The default mechanism of Windows is that even though the window is not active, you should be able to click directly on any active button on that form, right? Is this form in any way special?

Comment: This is only the case for a ToolStripButton, not a regular Button.  That's fixable.  Whatever problem you have is not.

Answer (score 0):

Well, here's a way to accomplish what You want (just attach a similar method to Your from's `MouseClick` event):

```
private void Form1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    var c = this.GetChildAtPoint(e.Location);
    this.InvokeOnClick(c, e);
}
```

This method has it's drawbacks though - for example the control will be clicked even though it's disabled etc., so You have to make sure the control under the cursor is "clickable" by yourself...